# What are examples of applications of the tree decomposition of a graph?

Tags: graphs, trees, applications

I am looking for *specific* applications of the [tree decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_decomposition) (of a graph), because I want to motivate its existence. What are examples of problems that are more easily solvable using the junction tree of a graph (rather than tackling the problem directly on the graph)? Please, provide also the references to the papers or books that mention these specific applications.

Comment: This is way too broad. Approximately speaking, anything that you can solve by dynamic programming on trees, you can solve by dynamic programming on tree decompositions.

Comment: Any instantiation of the general approach I mentioned is a specific example. Colourings, independent sets, constraint satisfaction problems, satisfiability problems, ...

Comment: I agree with David here. This is a good topic for a lecture or a book, but not a focused question. If it doesn't really matter to you what application is used as an example, you can make this question more focused by picking an application and asking a question about that application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of an application of the junction tree (or tree decomposition) of graph is described in the paper [Junction Tree Variational Autoencoder for Molecular Graph Generation](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.04364.pdf) (2019), by Wengong Jin, Regina Barzilay and Tommi Jaakkola.